# I'm trying to execute read in lines from file in C in a shell environment

Tags: c, shell, fork

I can compile the code, execute it with the file as a command line argument, but nothing happens. The interactive mode function prompts as normal, but not the batchMode function.

I'm trying to read in a line, and then execute that line.

example file

date

ls -la

cd

(Without spacing between lines. I can't get the formatting right on here.)

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>


#define bSize 1000


void driveLoop();
char *userInput(void);
void removeExit(char *original, char *subString); // removes string with substring "exit"
void batchMode(char *c);


int main(int argc, char **argv){

  char *fTemp;
  if (argc == 1)
    driveLoop(); // calls the loop function that accepts input and executes commands.

  else if (argc == 2)
    batchMode(&argv[1][0]);

  return 0;

}


void driveLoop(void){
  char *comTokens[100];
  char *tempTokens;
  char *command;
  char *cd;
  char *cdDir;
  char* cdTemp;
  char cdBuf[bSize];
  char checkExit[] = "exit";

  for (;;){


    printf("> ");
    command = userInput(); // reads input


    if (!*command) // allows for empty string error
      break;


    char *exitPtr = strstr(command, "exit"); // returns a value to a pointer if substring is found
    removeExit(command, "exit"); 
    puts(command); // updates the array after the function filter

    int i = 0;
    tempTokens = strtok(command, " \t\n"); // tokens are how the computer recognizes shell commands


    while (tempTokens && i < 99){ // geeksforgeeks.com
      comTokens[i++] = tempTokens;
      tempTokens = strtok(NULL, "\t\n");
    }


    if (strcmp(comTokens[0], "exit") == 0) // exit if input is "exit" only
      exit(0); 




    if(strcmp(comTokens[0], "cd") == 0){ // built in change directory command
      cd = getcwd(cdBuf, sizeof(cdBuf));
      cdDir = strcat(cd, "/");
      cdTemp = strcat(cdDir, comTokens[1]); // cplusplus.com reference
      chdir(cdTemp);
      continue;
    }

    comTokens[i] = NULL;


    pid_t cFork = fork(); // creates duplicate child process of parent


    if (cFork == (pid_t) - 1){ // error check
      perror("fork");
    }


    else if (cFork == 0) { // error codes found on cplusplus.com
      execvp(comTokens[0], comTokens);
      perror("exec");      
    }

    else { // children are returned. parent executes
      int status;
      waitpid(cFork, &status, 0);
      if (exitPtr != NULL){ // if substring exit was found, exit the program
    exit(0);
      }
    }


  }

}


char *userInput(void){  // referenced Linux man page - getline(3) (linux.die.net)
  char *input = NULL;
  size_t size = 0;
  getline(&input, &size, stdin); // updates the size as it goes along
  return input;
}


void removeExit(char *original, char *subString){ // removes exit from string
  char *ex;
  int len = strlen(subString); 
  while ((ex = strstr(original, subString))){ // Referenced from a Stack Overflow page.
    *ex = '\0';
    strcat(original, ex+len);
  }
}


void batchMode(char *c){


  char *tok[100];
  char *batchTokens;
  char *batchBuffer = NULL;
  size_t batchSize = 0;


  FILE *fp = fopen(c, "r");


  unsigned int line = 1;
  char buffer[bSize];


  while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)){

      int i = 0;


      char *toks = strtok(buffer, "\t\n");


      while (toks && i < 99){
           tok[i] = malloc (strlen(toks) + 1);
           strcpy(tok[i++], toks);
           toks = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
      }


      tok[i] = NULL;
          pid_t bFork = fork();


      if (bFork == (pid_t) - 1)
          perror("fork");


      else if (bFork == 0){
         execvp(tok[i], tok);
         perror("exec");
      }


      else {
        int status;
        waitpid(bFork, &status, 0);
      }

  }

}
```

side note. This is a re-attempt from a previous question that was locked for inadequate information. I've updated my code and tried to be as detailed as possible.
I'll happily provide anything further to help answer my question.

Thank you all.

*edit*
I put in a fprintf to verify that it reads the file in, and it does.

Comment: `tok[i++] = toks;` assigns the very same pointer to every `tok[i]` so at the end of your loop every `tok[i]` points to the last `toks`. You need to allocate storage. If you have `strdup`, then `tok[i++] = strdup(toks);` if not, then `tok[i] = malloc (strlen (toks) + 1);` (validate) then `strcpy (tok[i++], toks);`

Comment: No. There is only ONE `toks`. It is the token returned by `strtok` each time. You simply need to provide storage to save each of the tokens, because the next time you call `toks = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");`, `toks` will point to a new address. So just allocate storage, copy what `toks` currently points to, then call `strtok` (repeat) until you run out of tokens.

Comment: Okay, I updated my post and my program. Since it still does nothing, that must mean I have an issue somewhere else too right?

Comment: Let me take a look.

Comment: I added an example of my input file as well. It didn't show up perfectly in the post, but it's one command per line. No spacing between lines.

Comment: Two problems, (1) `execvp (tok[0], tok);` (not `tok[i]`) and (2) unless the command you are executing is in your `PATH`, you must have an absolute pathname to the command. (and (3), you must validate your file is open before attempting to read from it)

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I'll add a check for if open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note in your input file, the last command `cd` isn't a system command, it is a shell built-it, so you would expect it to fail (unless handled specially).

Allocating for each token (`tok[i]`) as discussed with either `strdup` (if available) or simply `malloc (strlen(toks) + 1);` allows you to copy the current token to the block of memory allocated. Now each `tok[i]` will reference the individual token saved (instead of all pointing to the last token -- due to all being assigned the same pointer)

The biggest logic error in `batchMode` as your call to `execvp` with `execvp (tok[i], tok);` instead of properly providing the file to execute as `tok[0]`. Be mindful if the file to execute isn't in your `PATH`, you must provide an absolute path in your input file.

Making the changes, your `batchMode` could be written as follows (and removing all the unused variables and moving `char *tok[100];` within the `while` loop so it is declared within that scope):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
...
void batchMode(char *c)
{
    char buffer[bSize];
    FILE *fp = fopen (c, "r");

    if (!fp) {
        perror ("fopen-c");
        return;
    }

    while (fgets (buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) {

        int i = 0;
        char *tok[100];
        char *toks = strtok(buffer, " \t\n");

        while (toks && i < 99){
            tok[i] = malloc (strlen(toks) + 1);
            strcpy(tok[i++], toks);
            toks = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
        }

        tok[i] = NULL;
            pid_t bFork = fork();

        if (bFork == (pid_t) - 1)
            perror("fork");
        else if (bFork == 0){
            execvp (tok[0], tok);
            perror("exec");
        }
        else {
            int status;
            waitpid(bFork, &status, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Input Files**

I have two simple input files tested:

```
$ cat dat/toksfile.txt
echo hello
echo goodbye

$ cat dat/toksfile2.txt
date
ls -al dat/toksfile.txt
cd
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/shellorbatch dat/toksfile.txt
hello
goodbye

$ ./bin/shellorbatch dat/toksfile2.txt
Tue Feb  4 23:47:00 CST 2020
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 24 Feb  4 23:24 dat/toksfile.txt
exec: No such file or directory
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions:

Comment: One question, disregarding the tok[i] part (that was an unreverted fix attempt), why would my toks[i++] part work in interactive mode, but not in batch? That is confusing me.

Comment: I am pretty sure you cleared it up for me by pointing out that getline was created to allocate storage and make input easier. C is so barebones. It's definitely fun to code with, but I am gonna have to go back and relearn the basics on pointers.

Comment: Remember, a pointer is just a normal variable that holds the address for something else as its value. In other words, a pointer *points to* the address where something else can be found. Where you normally think of a variable holding an immediate values, such as `int a = 5;`, a pointer would simply hold the address where `5` is stored in memory. (e.g. `int *b; b = &a;`) So now we say `b` *points* to `a` (because `b` holds `a`'s address as its value).

Comment: As far as why `driveLoop(void)` works -- you are more lucky than good. It should be updated to allocate and copy as well. The basic problem remains. You assign the same pointer to every pointer in the `comTokens` array with `comTokens[i++] = tempTokens;`. The fact that it "appears to work" is classic *Undefined Behavior* -- it could just as well segfault because the last address held by `tempTokens` is `NULL`.